# onbeforeUnload without return or no dialogbox show

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, browser, richfaces

I am developing a web application in java EE with richfaces.
There is a link, which logs out the user.
When the user navigates away from the page or shuts the browser down I should logout the user because I have to know when he left our page.
Here is a snippet:

```
  function fireEvent(obj,evt){

      var fireOnThis = obj;
      if( document.createEvent ) {
          var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
          evObj.initEvent( evt, true, false );
          fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
      } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
          fireOnThis.fireEvent('on'+evt);
      }
  }

  var popit = true;
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      if(popit == true) {
         fireEvent(document.getElementById("logout_form:logout_link"),'click');
      }
  }
```

This is working only browser close, not navigation away or refresh.
I changed fireEvent(...) to return " ". Everything works good.
If I type return "" after fireEvent(...) it works well, just I don't wanna show the dialog box.
How could I do this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [synchronous](http://debugtheweb.com/test/xhr/sync.asp) AJAX call, then put your shutdown method in the callback:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   // This template uses no error checking, it's just concept code to be
   // expanded on.

   // Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
   var AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();  

   // Handle ready state changes ( ignore them until readyState = 4 )
   AJAX.onreadystatechange= function() { if (AJAX.readyState!=4) return false; }

   // we're passing false so this is a synchronous request.
   // The script will stall until the document has been loaded.
   // the open statement depends on a global variable titled _userID.
   AJAX.open("GET", 'about:blank', false);
   AJAX.send(null);
}
```