# In the Navigation Timing API, why does the unload event fire during the load of the destination page?

Tags: http, navigation, w3c

[image]

Why is the unload event in that particular part of the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

The unload event is the initial event that is fired as the user transitions from one page to another. If there are any [synchronous requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384042/onbeforeunload-without-return-or-no-dialogbox-show/13999400#13999400) during the `beforeUnload` phase, the subsequent unload phase unbinds them and empties the DOM as part of the request for the current page.